(Flet python) Complicação com TextField e aplicação de máscara com on_change
Estou fazendo um programa que tem tela de cadastro e tals, e no campo de CNPJ, optei por colocar uma máscara dinâmica, de modo que ela seja aplicada enquanto a pessoa digita o  CNPJ dela, porém, quando executei o código, quando eu fui digitar o meu CNPJ, o início da máscara começou a ser aplicada, e isso fez com que todo o campo fosse selecionado, o que não acontecia antes de colocar a view=WEB_BROWSER, como posso resolver isso, deixando a view=WEB_BROWSER?
from itertools import cycle
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1",
    user="root",
    port=3306,
    password="password",
    database="database1"
)
cursor = mydb.cursor()

def limpar_campo(e):
    e.control.error_text    = ""
    e.control.update()

def cnpj_exists(var_cnpj):
    # conexao_mysql = criar_conexao()
    # cursor = conexao_mysql.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute("SELECT cnpj from database1 WHERE cnpj = %s", (var_cnpj,))
        resultado = cursor.fetchone()

        if resultado:
            return True  # Email existe
        else:
            return False  # Email não existe
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Erro ao consultar o banco de dados:", error)

LENGTH_CNPJ = 14
def is_cnpj_valido(cnpj: str) -> bool:
        if len(cnpj) != LENGTH_CNPJ:
            print("False 1 ")
            return False

        if cnpj in (c * LENGTH_CNPJ for c in "1234567890"):
            print("False 2")
            return False

        cnpj_r = cnpj[::-1]
        for i in range(2, 0, -1):
            cnpj_enum = zip(cycle(range(2, 10)), cnpj_r[i:])
            dv = sum(map(lambda x: int(x[1]) * x[0], cnpj_enum)) * 10 % 11
            if cnpj_r[i - 1:i] != str(dv % 10):
                print("False 3")
                return False
        print("True")
        return True

def desmarcarar_cnpj(cnpj):
    parte_1 = cnpj[0:2]
    parte_2 = cnpj[3:6]
    parte_3 = cnpj[7:10]
    parte_4 = cnpj[11:15]
    parte_5 = cnpj[16:19]
    resultado = parte_1 + parte_2 + parte_3 + parte_4 + parte_5
    return resultado

def verificar_cnpj(e):
    cnpj_valido = None
    cnpj_value = desmarcarar_cnpj(e.control.value)
    if not is_cnpj_valido(cnpj_value):
        e.control.error_text = "CNPJ inválido!"  # Exibe a mensagem de erros
        cnpj_valido = False
    else:
        e.control.error_text = None  # Limpa a mensagem de erro se o CNPJ for válido
        cnpj_valido = True
    # IF para conferir de o CNPJ existe ou não
    if cnpj_valido == True:
        if not cnpj_exists(cnpj_value) == True:
            e.control.error_text = None  # Limpa a mensagem de erro se o CNPJ for válido
        else:
            e.control.error_text = "CNPJ já existe!"
    e.page.update()

def formatar_cnpj(valor): 
    """Formata o CNPJ no padrão 99.999.999/9999-99."""
    apenas_numeros = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, valor))  # Remove caracteres não numéricos
    apenas_numeros = apenas_numeros[:14]  # Limita o CNPJ a 14 dígitos

    parte_1 = apenas_numeros[0:2]
    parte_2 = apenas_numeros[2:5]
    parte_3 = apenas_numeros[5:8]
    parte_4 = apenas_numeros[8:12]
    parte_5 = apenas_numeros[12:14]

    if len(apenas_numeros) >= 13:
        return parte_1+'.'+parte_2+'.'+parte_3+'/'+parte_4+'.'+parte_5
    if len(apenas_numeros) >=9:
        return parte_1+'.'+parte_2+'.'+parte_3+'/'+parte_4
    if len(apenas_numeros) >=6:
        return parte_1+'.'+parte_2+'.'+parte_3
    if len(apenas_numeros) >=3:
        return parte_1+'.'+parte_2
    if len(apenas_numeros) <=2:
        return apenas_numeros

def atualizar_cnpj(e):
    valor_atual = e.control.value
    valor_formatado = formatar_cnpj(valor_atual)

    # Atualizar o campo somente se o valor mudou
    if valor_atual != valor_formatado:
        e.control.value = valor_formatado
        e.page.update()
        e.control.focus()

def create_input_fields():
    cnpjtxt = TextField(label="CNPJ", on_focus=lambda e=Page:limpar_campo(e), on_change=atualizar_cnpj, on_blur=verificar_cnpj)    

    return cnpjtxt
def empresa(page):
    page.theme_mode = ThemeMode.LIGHT
    cnpjtxt = create_input_fields()
    grid = Container(
            width=840,
            height=320,
            margin=10,
            padding=10,
            bgcolor=Colors.WHITE,
            border_radius=border_radius.all(15),
            shadow=BoxShadow(
                spread_radius=2,
                blur_radius=15,
                color=Colors.with_opacity(0.4, Colors.BLACK),
                offset=Offset(5, 5),
            ),
            alignment=alignment.center,
            content=Column(
                [
                    Text(
                        f"Cadastro de Empresa",
                        weight=FontWeight.BOLD,
                        size=20
                    ),
                    Row([cnpjtxt]),
                ],
                horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
            )
        )
    display = Container(
        content=Column(
            [
                grid,
            ],
            horizontal_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
        )
    )

    # page.add(display)
    
# Executar o aplicativo
    page.add(display)

app(target=empresa, view=WEB_BROWSER)```

